# degree lexicographic monomial ordering

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

With respect to deglex X>Y, what would the leading monomials of these polynomials be?

$f_1=XY^3-X^2$ and $f_2=-X^3Y^3-4X^2Y^3+3X^2Y$

My understanding is that you prioritise X over Y based on their degree. So surely the leading monomials would be:

$X^2$ and $X^3Y^3$ right? Or am I understanding it wrong? The leading monomial for $f_1$ is $XY^3$ according to the answers.

Comment: in my lecture course, leading monomials are defined without the coefficient. Leading term = leading monomial * leading coefficient.  This doesn't explain why they have $XY^3$ for the leading monomial of $f_1$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lexicographic where you simply prioritize $X$ over $Y$, and then there's *graded* lexicographic where you first choose the highest total degree and then prioritize $X$ over $Y$ to break ties.

I suspect "degree lexicographic" means "graded lexicographic", hence for $f_1$ the leading monomial is $XY^3$ because it has total degree $4$, whereas $X^2$ has total degree $2$.

For regular lexicographic you are correct that $X^2$ would be the leading term for $f_1$.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you!